# List with the names of points in a given radius for all rows of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geo

I have a dataframe like:

```
projectName latitude    longitude
a          56.864229    60.609576
b          55.810413    37.701168
c          55.924912    37.966033
d          56.804987    60.590667
e          55.806000    37.569863
```

I want to get a list of points in a given radius for each point.
Example for 30 km it should be like that:

```
projectName latitude    longitude   30km
a          56.864229    60.609576  [d]
b          55.810413    37.701168  [c, e]
c          55.924912    37.966033  [b, e]
d          56.804987    60.590667  [a]
e          55.806000    37.569863  [b, c]
```

How can I get this most quickly?

Comment: b and c are 20.8km away, not 10

Comment: @radjaz, alternatively, u can also use 'geodesic' library, implemented below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the pairwise [`haversine_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html) and filter the values:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances

DIST = 10 # distance in km

tmp = np.radians(df.set_index('projectName')[['latitude', 'longitude']])

# compute pairwise distance
keep = haversine_distances(tmp)*6371 <= DIST

# remove self (e.g. a/a)
np.fill_diagonal(keep, False)

# combine the strings
df[f'{DIST}km'] = (keep @ (tmp.index+',')).str[:-1]
```

Output (for 10 and 30 km):

```
  projectName   latitude  longitude 10km 30km
0           a  56.864229  60.609576    d    d
1           b  55.810413  37.701168    e  c,e
2           c  55.924912  37.966033       b,e
3           d  56.804987  60.590667    a    a
4           e  55.806000  37.569863    b  b,c
```

If you want a list:

```
df[f'{DIST}km'] = [tmp.index[x].tolist() for x in keep]
```

Output:

```
  projectName   latitude  longitude 10km    30km
0           a  56.864229  60.609576  [d]     [d]
1           b  55.810413  37.701168  [e]  [c, e]
2           c  55.924912  37.966033   []  [b, e]
3           d  56.804987  60.590667  [a]     [a]
4           e  55.806000  37.569863  [b]  [b, c]
```

Answer (score 1):

With alternative library (geodesic), simply to use.

```
distance = geodesic((Latitude1, Logitude1), (Latitude2, Logitude2)).kilometers
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'projectName': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        'latitude': [56.864229, 55.810413, 55.924912, 56.804987, 55.806000],
        'longitude': [60.609576, 37.701168, 37.966033, 60.590667, 37.569863]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def points_in_radius(df, row, radius):
    result = []
    for _, r in df.iterrows():
        distance = geodesic((row['latitude'], row['longitude']), (r['latitude'], r['longitude'])).kilometers
        if 0 < distance <= radius:
            result.append(r['projectName'])
    return result

radius = 10
df['{}km'.format(radius)] = df.apply(lambda row: points_in_radius(df, row, radius), axis=1)

radius = 30
df['{}km'.format(radius)] = df.apply(lambda row: points_in_radius(df, row, radius), axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  projectName   latitude  longitude 10km    30km
0           a  56.864229  60.609576  [d]     [d]
1           b  55.810413  37.701168  [e]  [c, e]
2           c  55.924912  37.966033   []  [b, e]
3           d  56.804987  60.590667  [a]     [a]
4           e  55.806000  37.569863  [b]  [b, c]
```